# How to create a application that works both on Google App Engine and Local tomcat server?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am creating a java based application and i want to use google app engine for its deployment. But i want this application to be movable to other servers like tomcat etc on my local or other machines. So i though want to use google app engine. But want to keep my application independent of any Google specific things. Can somebody summarize the points i must take care of. I want to keep it independent both from application and database layer perspective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I am not master in google app engine however the thumb rule to make your webapp portable is to use standard specification APIs instead of vendor specific APIs. For example if your app is using google app engine UserServive (com.google.appengine.api.users.UserService) or data store  com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService , if is tightly bound with Google app engine and can not be migrated to standalone tomcat engine.
To loose couple your database for further migration you should consider using MySQl schema in google app engine. Because in future you can host your database anywhere by just taking a dump. Also, you should use JDBC apis/JPA for database operations from your application using [MySQL JDBC JAR](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)

To summarize, you should avoid any API call which has com.google.appengine* import in your source. Also, you should have your own mysql schema running in google app engine cloud.

Comment: Ajay is Google Cloud SQL free to use as i am just experimenting with it.

Comment: See the pricing plan for google cloud sql below https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/billing

Comment: i dont want to actually use a paid plan, Can you suggest me how to use google datastore with minimal coupling. May be limiting to a simple configuration file, so that when i move to local i just change that file and be all set? I dont know much about JPA.

Comment: Sushil, if you want to use datastore then for sure you will have very tight coupling. Also, Datastore comes with limited free quota https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Datastore after that you have to take billing plan. It is advisable to go for dedicated schema hosting of mysql for you requirements.

Comment: Ajay at this time i am just evaluating Google App Engine if i should go for it or not, Developing Sample Applications as assignments for Students and we may think of scaling them or not later. Since u mention google uses JPA cannnot, JPA be configured to change the database mapping later when i want to go independent?

Comment: Datastore can not be used with JPA options. So you cant change it in future with Datastore option. Changing database can only be done if you use dedicated schema of cloud-sql (MySql) and configure the JPA/JDBC for the same. Future migration of data in this case wold be easy by just changin the config option of JPA/ or connetion setting of JDBC.

Comment: If there is some limitations on the Google cloud standard environment you must solve, the solution will be complex. Such as the standard environment, you cannot run long live thread, such as use Firebase Admin SDK post data. You can only use the Task Queue on GCP. This will break the migration.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can and it's only a matter of design.
Just an example: if your application need user authentication, you can create an interface `AuthenticationService` and two implementations:

- `GAEAuthenticationService` for the Google App Engine
- `FakeAuthenticationService` for local tests running with *jetty* (for example)
- `DataSourceAuthenticationService` for authentication based on a `DataSource`

You can do the same think with persistence, scheduler, etc... the only thing to do is:

***define the objects you need and use interfaces when you need different implementations that depends on platforms***